# Python Protocol Allowing Optional Attributes

Tags: python, protocols, type-hinting, python-typing, duck-typing

Suppose I have a protocol `Foo`.

```
from typing import Protocol, Optional


class Foo(Protocol):
    val: Optional[int]
```

And a function like the following:

```
def func(obj: Foo) -> None:
    if obj.val is not None:
        print(obj.val)
```

I would expect that either `ImplA` and `ImplB` (shown below) should be an acceptable argument for `func`, since `val: int` is a more specific than `val: Optional[int]`.

```
class ImplA:
    val: int


class ImplB:
    val: Optional[int]

a = ImplA()
b = ImplB()

func(a)  # Argument 1 to "func" has incompatible type "ImplA"; expected "Foo"
func(b)  # It works
```

As it doesn't work, I have to define `Bar` and take the union of both classes. However, is there a way to construct a protocol such that both `val: Optional[int]` and `val: int` will be accepted without `Union`?

```
class Bar(Protocol):
    val: int

def func(obj: Union[Foo, Bar]): ...
```

EDIT:

To achieve this, we need to make sure that the type of val is covariant. As far as I see now, it looks like that `Protocol` defines it to be an invariant. Is it thus impossible to achieve my requirements?

Answer (score 2):

The problem is that you have defined not only a covariant getter, but a contravariant setter. Consider the following:

```py
def func2(obj: Foo) -> None:
    if obj.val is not None:
        print(obj.val)
        obj.val = None  # Fine: val is optional in Foo

x = ImplA(val = 10)
func2(x)  # is x a valid Foo?
print(x.val + 1)  # runtime error!
```

By the type definition of ImplA, `x.val` is `int` so the typechecker must allow the final print. But `func2` is valid, as it's only using protocol methods. The only way to prevent this code typechecking is to prevent x being passed to func2. This makes sense as it doesn't have the None-accepting val setter used in func2.

The following will work as you intended:

```py
class Foo(Protocol):
  @property
  def val(self) -> Optional[int]:
    ...
```

With this definition, the typechecker will complain at the final line of `func2`, as it is no longer able to access a setter. Your original example will now typecheck.

---

By the way, I used the terms "covariant" and "contravariant" because you did, and they do *feel* right, but technically your type isn't covariant or contravariant at all because it's not generic. We could fix that with explicit use of a TypeVar:

```py
T_co = TypeVar("T_co", covariant=True)

class Foo(Protocol, Generic[T_co]):
  val: T_co
```

This would fail typechecking right here as, now your intent is obvious, the typechecker can tell you your definition is not covariant.

Answer (score -2):

I ran your code and it raised an error for both func(a) and func(b). The error is related to

`if obj.val is not none:`

because none of the objects have the attribute "val". I tested the code with Python 3.9.9.

I modified the clause to test if the object has the attribute val, hopefully this helps.

```
from typing import Protocol, Optional


class Foo(Protocol):
    val: Optional[int]


def func(obj: Foo) -> None:
    if hasattr(obj, 'val'):
        print(obj.val)
    else:
        print(f"{obj} variable val is undefined")


class ImplA:
    val: int


class ImplB:
    val: Optional[int]


print("Accessing func with ImplA and ImplB before initializing val")
a = ImplA()
b = ImplB()
func(a)
func(b)

print("Accessing func with ImplA and ImplB after initializing val")
a = ImplA()
a.val = 2
b = ImplB()
b.val = 20
func(a)
func(b)
```

Comment: The question was about typechecking, e.g. mypy, not runtime behaviour, so while technically, yes, the example code has this issue, you haven't solved the OP's actual problem unfortunately